# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter Executing but Response is HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

The `ContainerRequestFilter` named `AppAuthenticationFilter` executes properly and yet the response is `HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized`.

`AppAuthenticationFilter` is located in `daksh.userevents.storage.apps.api`.

[Link for the project](https://github.com/dakshj/User-Events-Storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by registering the multiple API Resource Packages as well as the multiple `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation classes in `web.xml`.

**Please Note:**
For resources: Use the packages in which the classes are contained.
For providers: Use the class names.
Keep the packages semi-colon/comma separated.

**Example:**

For Resource Packages:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        my.first.package;
        my.second.package;
        my.third.package
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

For Providers:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        my.nth.package.XYZFilter;
        my.mth.package.ABCFilter
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```